# Problemas al importar un paquete propio en Go

Tags: go

estoy apenas comenzando en este lenguaje de programacion llamado Golang, estoy en la parte de exportar paquetes propios hacia el paquete main, a la hora de exportarlos y colocar la direccion en el codigo, los  slash estan de esta manera "/" y de esa manera tambien esta en la terminal, pero la direccion en el directorio tiene el slash invertido "\" entonces me da error al compilarlo, que podria hacer en ese caso? en la imagen pueden apreciar como es la direccion en el explorador de archivos, como es en la terminal y el error que me lanza, muchas gracias

[image: en la imagen pueden apreciar como es la direccion en el directorio y el error que me da en la termianl]

Answer (score 0):

Segun se ve en el codigo el paquete es parte del proyecto y la mejor forma de referenciarlo es de forma relativa, de esta manera como te muestro

```
import "./Saludar"
```

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola Lyon!

También estoy empezando con Golang, hace poco tuve una situación similar y logré solucionarlo usando el sistema de modulos de Golang.

Para hacerlo puedes escribir en la consola.

```
go mod init github.com/lyondeveloper/Curso
```

Y luego podras importarlo usando

```
import "github.com/lyondeveloper/Curso/Paquetes/Saludar"
```

De esta manera, podras importar tus paquetes en el proyecto, sin necesidad de que este se encuentre en el GOPATH.

En el siguiente enlace puedes encontrar más información a la documentación de Go Modules [Go Modules Reference](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-init)

El video a continuación me sirvió como guía: [Local packages - Golang](https://youtu.be/3887wZTMvLw)

Espero sea de ayuda.